# How to properly use MUI FormControl component?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm coding a contact form using **React** and **MaterialUI**.
I have some `TextField` components and one `RadioGroup` with two options.

MUI's documentation only shows `FormControl` wrapping a `FormLabel` for its `RadioGroup`.

Should my `TextField` components also be inside the same `FormControl`?

My code (simplified) is like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <TextField label="firstName" />
  <TextField label="lastName" />
  <TextField label="email" />
  <TextField label="phone" />
  <TextField label="message" />
  <FormControl>
    <FormLabel id="contact-options-label">Contact Options</FormLabel>
    <RadioGroup aria-labelledby="contact-options-label">
      <FormControlLabel
        value="option1"
        label="Option 1"
        control={<Radio color="secondary" />}
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        value="option2"
        label="Option 2"
        control={<Radio color="secondary" />}
      />
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</form>
```

Am I using **FormControl** properly in this case?